# Drawing a grid with a different color for each edge in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

It's all in the title. I'm trying to plot a grid in python, with a specific color for each edge. Here is a view of what I would like to obtain, made from tikz.

[image]

The tikz code gives me a roadmap for how to proceed in python: I just run two loops of coordinates and draw by hand the edge (x, y)--(x+1,y).

I see two ways of implementing this in python, but can't find the exact syntax/objects/packages to use (most of the time, people just call the grid functions, in which the axis can be given a color, but this is quite different):

- is there a way to access the specific edges using the grid function ? If so, how are they indexed ?
- or is there a way to draw by hand, the segment (0,0) to (0,1) and the segment (0,1) to (0,2) and plot them in the same graph, side by side ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matplotlib.path`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html) can be used to draw polygons or also just a polyline following a specific path.
See also the [matplotlib Path Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html).

**Brief example with line segments in different colors:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath


def draw_polyline(start_x, start_y, delta_x, delta_y, color):
    Path = mpath.Path
    path_data = [
    (Path.MOVETO, (start_x, start_y)),
    (Path.MOVETO, (start_x + delta_x, start_y + delta_y)),
    ]
    codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
    path = mpath.Path(verts, codes)
    x, y = zip(*path.vertices)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, f'{color}-', lw=3)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (5,5))

draw_polyline(0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 'k')
draw_polyline(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, 'g')
draw_polyline(0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1, 'r')
draw_polyline(0.2, 0.3, -0.1, 0.0, 'y')

plt.show()
```

**Notes:**

- The first `MOVETO` sets the starting point, an explicit endpoint isn't required.
- `lw` is linewidth
- for sure the `draw_polyline` function and it's calls may need to be adapted to your data (seems like a lot of lines and maybe the coloring follows a specific function...), but the code should show the principle of using `path` for this

---

Concerning using the grid I'd doubt that the 'segments' can be separated (but maybe others know a way).

[Matplotlib: Change color of individual grid lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073616/matplotlib-change-color-of-individual-grid-lines) shows a way to color individual grid lines, but 'only' the whole line at once and not in segments.